# Magento Category with Category Images

Tags: php, magento

I am facing one problem, So i am here to get Some solutions form you! I want to display category menu with category images near to each categories with in that menu.

So when i click on menu if that category contain sub-category it show the name of all those sub-categories with images near to it's name like

example

```
parent1
  =>sub1 <Image of sub1 category>
  =>sub2 <Image of Sub2 category>
  =>sub3 <Image of sub3 category>
```

Same way i have parent2, parent3 etc., which contain sub-categories same way as i mention here.

So when i click on any parent category it will listed me sub-categories with it's images!

If anybody having Idea about this then let me know how to do this.

Waiting for your response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image link using

```
$_imageUrl=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()
```

Follow [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/how_to_create_categories_grid_list_with_images) wiki from detailed walk-through.

Comment: @darshan.dodiya, What is not working? Did you follow the link and do?

Comment: yes i follow it! but i think i have to do some customization for that!

Comment: I don't want to display category in list page i want category image under drop down menu. now i think you get the idea what i want!